# NMAP usage questions

Tags: nmap

I'm **very, very** new to cyber security. Going through some training at the moment, but I'm confused.

Right now I'm tasked with using Kali Linux to scan a Mint Linux VM help find an unauthorized server hosted on their network and find their IP address. I have some basic questions really:

1) My instructions states that the Mint Linux VM I have "has provided your Kali Linux machine with access to the same network as the vulnerable server". How do I know? Is this just stated?

2) How would I go about even starting? How do target NMAP at the Mint Linux?

Thanks

Comment: try bridge adapter ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) What that seems to be telling you is that the vulnerable server that you are looking into is on the same network as your Kali Linux machine. This means that you should be able to find it by scanning your local network.

2) To start using nmap I suggest that you run the command `man nmap` in your terminal and read through the information there that should give you a good idea of where to start. You can also go to [https://nmap.org](http://nmap.org) and read through the reference guide provided by nmap. That is the best way to learn how to use this tool. Play around with the features that come with it and read up on the things that you do not understand this will help you to gain a better understanding of using nmap and analyzing networks.

Answer (score 0):

nmap allows you to scan ip ranges. So you can start with finding your ip addres by running `ifconfig`. You can then scan the local network like this (I'm asuming the size of your subnet here):

`nmap <your ip>/24`

If the Mint server doesn't respond to pings, you need to add:

`nmap -Pn <your ip>/24`

That should show you some active devices on the network. For more examples see:

https://nmap.org/book/man-examples.html